# MongoDB cursor and write operations

Tags: mongodb, cursor

I am using **MongoDB** to save data about products. After writing the initial large data-set (24mio items) I would like to change all the items in the collection.

Therefore I use a cursor to iterate over the whole collection. Then I want to add a "row" or field to every item in the collection. With large data-sets this is not working. There were only 180000 items updated. On a small scale it is working. Is that normal behavior?

Is *MongoDB* not supposed to support writes while iterating with a cursor over the whole collection?

What would be a good practice to do that instead?

Answer (score 0):

For larger collections, you might run into snapshotting problems. When you add data to the object and save it, it will grow, forcing mongodb to move the document around. Then you might find the object twice.

You can either use [`$snapshot`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/) in your query, or use a stable order such as `sort({"_id":1})`. Note that you can't use both.

Also make sure to use at least acknowledged write concern.

Comment: Thanks! I use snapshot. That doesn't help. But I could try to sort it instead.

Answer (score 0):

When we had a similar problem, we fetched data in 100k(with some test) chunks. It's a quick and simple solution.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. It might take a while since processing takes a long time, but I will get back to you :)

Comment: If you are dealing with 24 million records, it should take some time :)